# vim: delete from cursor position to n characters before end of line

Tags: vim

In vim, with

```
dg_
```

you can delete the actual cursor position to end of line.
How can I delete the actual position to end of line minus some number of characters?

example:

```
this<cursor> is a ... many words ... line
```

How  do I delete from `<cursor>` position to `li` of line word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say for 4 characters:

```
v$4hd
```

- v - visual / select mode.
- $ - go to end of line.
- 4h - step back 4 chars.
- d - delete selection.

Or you can just say skip the last word:

```
v$bhd
```

That will leave only the last word standing.

Comment: but I don't like delete from beginning of line, I like delete from actual cursor position to end of line minus some characters

Comment: @juanpablo my bad. I fixed it. Should work now.